# How do I connect and retrieve data from Google Cloud SQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-sql

The only tutorials I could find used unfamiliar alternative resources, like app engine, composer, github, proxies, other plugins.

Isn't it possible to simply connect to it using pure PHP?

For example, in the following code would I need to modify to get data from Google Cloud SQL?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: you probably dont want to use google-cloud if you consider "app engine, composer, github, proxies, other plugins." to be  "unfamiliar alternative resources" there are lots of alternatives that are probably more your speed

Answer (score 2):

Google App Engine connects from inside of Google servers to the Cloud SQL instance via proxy, but the **Cloud SQL instance is just a managed MySQL instance**. So, if you want just to connect from the outside with PHP code and without a proxy, then you just need to authorize your IP (here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#appaccessIP) in the Cloud SQL instance.

And then, you should modify the code to change “localhost” to your Google Cloud SQL instance public IP (with its proper username, password and dbname). You can find the public IP here: http://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances/

But, if you still want to have a look around PHP on Google App Engine, check that link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql